# Predicting relative risk with predict.coxph, simPH and the formula

Tags: r, prediction, cox-regression

There is a great [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44896/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-predict-coxph) about the interpretation of the `predict.coxph()` output. However, I keep getting different results comparing the output from `predict.coxph`, `simPH` and the formula for relative risk. Since my hypothesis includes a quadratic effect, I am going to include a polynomial with power 2 in my example.

I use the example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905934/plot-a-quadratic-relation-for-a-predictor-of-a-cox-regression-with-r/51137796#51137796) post.

```
data("lung")
```

Predicting relative risk with predict()

```
# Defining the quadratic predictor
lung$meal.cal_q <- lung$meal.cal^2

# conduct a cox regression with the predictor meal.cal, its quadratic version and some covariates.
cox_mod <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~
                 ph.karno + pat.karno + meal.cal + meal.cal_q,
                 data = lung)

# a vector of fitted values to predict for
meal.cal_new <- seq(min(lung$meal.cal, na.rm= TRUE), max(lung$meal.cal, 
na.rm= TRUE), by= 1)

# a vector of fitted values to predict for, the quadratic effect
meal.cal_q_new <- meal.cal_new^2

# the length of the vector with the values to predict for
n <- length(meal.cal_new)

# a dataframe with all the values to predict for
lung_new <- data.frame(ph.karno= rep(mean(lung$ph.karno, na.rm= TRUE), n), 
                       pat.karno= rep(mean(lung$pat.karno, na.rm= TRUE), n), 
                       meal.cal= meal.cal_new, 
                       meal.cal_q = meal.cal_q_new)

# predict the relative risk
lung_new$rel_risk <- predict(cox_mod, lung_new,  type= "risk")
```

Predicting the relative risk with the formula (see the [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44896/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-predict-coxph) mentioned above)

```
# Defining the quadratic predictor
lung$meal.cal_q <- lung$meal.cal^2

# run a cox regression with the predictor meal.cal, its quadratic version and some covariates.
cox_mod <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~
               ph.karno + pat.karno + meal.cal + meal.cal_q,
             data = lung)

# a vector of fitted values to predict for
meal.cal_new <- seq(min(lung$meal.cal, na.rm= TRUE), max(lung$meal.cal, 
                                                     na.rm= TRUE), by= 1)

# a vector of fitted values to predict for, the quadratic effect
meal.cal_q_new <- meal.cal_new^2

# length of the vector to predict for
n <- length(meal.cal_new)

# A dataframe with the values to make the prediction for
lung_new2 <- data.frame(
             ph.karno= rep(mean(lung$ph.karno, na.rm= TRUE), n), 
             pat.karno= rep(mean(lung$pat.karno, na.rm= TRUE), n), 
             meal.cal= meal.cal_new, 
             meal.cal_q = meal.cal_q_new)

# A dataframe with the values to compare the prediction with
lung_new_mean <- data.frame(
                 ph.karno= rep(mean(lung$ph.karno, na.rm= TRUE), n), 
                 pat.karno= rep(mean(lung$pat.karno, na.rm= TRUE), n), 
                 meal.cal= rep(mean(lung$meal.cal, na.rm= TRUE), n), 
                 meal.cal_q = rep(mean(lung$meal.cal_q, na.rm= TRUE), n))

# extract the coefficients
coefCPH <- coef(cox_mod)

# make the prediction for the values of interest
cox_risk <-
exp(coefCPH["ph.karno"] * lung_new2[ , "ph.karno"] +
    coefCPH["pat.karno"] * lung_new2[ , "pat.karno"] +
    coefCPH["meal.cal"] * lung_new2[ , "meal.cal"] +
    coefCPH["meal.cal_q"] * lung_new2[ , "meal.cal_q"])

# make the predictions for the values to compare with
cox_risk_mean <-
exp(coefCPH["ph.karno"] * lung_new_mean[ , "ph.karno"] +
    coefCPH["pat.karno"] * lung_new_mean[ , "pat.karno"] +
    coefCPH["meal.cal"] * lung_new_mean[ , "meal.cal"] +
    coefCPH["meal.cal_q"] * lung_new_mean[ , "meal.cal_q"])

# calculate the relative risk
lung_new2$rel_risk <- unlist(cox_risk)/ unlist(cox_risk_mean)
```

Now the plot with the predicted relative risk using `predict()` and using the formula:

```
ggplot(lung_new, aes(meal.cal, rel_risk)) +
       geom_smooth() +
       geom_smooth(data= lung_new2, col= "red")
```

[image]

The plot shows that the predictions are different. I do not understand why this is the case, although the [mentioned post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44896/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-predict-coxph) shows that the predict function and the formula should give the same result.

Because of this confusion I tried to solve the problem with the `simPH` package. Here is what I did:

```
# Defining the quadratic predictor
lung$meal.cal_q <- lung$meal.cal^2

# run a cox regression with the predictor, its quadratic version and some covariates.

cox_mod <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~
                 ph.karno + pat.karno + meal.cal + meal.cal_q,
                 data = lung)

# a vector of fitted values to predict for
meal.cal_new <- seq(min(lung$meal.cal, na.rm= TRUE),
                    max(lung$meal.cal, na.rm= TRUE), by= 1)

# length of the vector to predict for
n <- length(meal.cal_new)

# A vector with the values to compare the prediction with
meal.cal_new_mean <- rep(mean(lung$meal.cal, na.rm= TRUE), n)

# running 100 simulations per predictor value with coxsimPoly
Sim <- coxsimPoly(obj= cox_mod, b = "meal.cal", pow = 2,
                  qi = "Relative Hazard",
                  Xj = meal.cal_new,
                  Xl = meal.cal_new_mean,
                  ci = .95,
                  nsim = 100,
                  extremesDrop = FALSE)

# plot the result
simGG(Sim)
```

This gives an empty plot with the warning

```
Warning messages:
1: In min(obj$sims[, x]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(obj$sims[, x]) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

And the Sim$`sims`object appears indeed to be empty.

My questions are:

1. Why do the results from `predict()` and the use of the formula differ?
2. Why does the `simPH` package not calculate the relative risk?
3. Which method should I choose? My hypothesis is a quadratic effect in a cox regression and I need a plot for this predictor with its relative risk (compared to the predictor being at its mean value), just like in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer to the **simPH** issue: the polynomial terms need to be specified in the `coxph` call using the `I` function, e.g.:

```
cox_mod <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~
                 ph.karno + pat.karno + meal.cal + I(meal.cal^2),
             data = lung)
```

(The error handling in your use case is pretty poor.)

Using this modification (and 1000 simulations) with your code above should return something like:

[image]

#### Differences between simPH and `predict`

My guess to the differences is that simPH doesn't create confidence intervals around the transformed point estimates like `predict`. It draws simulations from the multivariate normal distribution specified by the fitted model, then shows the central 50% and 95% of this simulated distribution. The central line is just the median of the sims. It is explicitly a different logic from `predict`. For very non-monotonic quantities of interest, like this one, `predict` point estimates give highly substantively misleading results compared to simPH. There is little evidence for such a form based on 4 observations.

Comment: Off the top of my head guesses about why the three methods provide different predictions:

- The two first examples don't use exactly the same fitted values and/or use slightly different ways of calculating the quantities of interest which creates transformation bias [Rainey (2017)](http://www.carlislerainey.com/papers/bias.pdf).

- `simPH` explicitly includes uncertainty in the plot. The polynomial coefficients are not statistically sig. There are also only ~4 observations above 1500. So there is really no evidence for the bend back down (similar story for low values).

Comment: Right, there're only four obs for x> 1500 and in the plots for predict() and the plot for the formula I did not include confidence intervals to depict this uncertainty. But I would have expected that in simPH the uncertainty is taken into account by creating wider confidence intervals. Or does this uncertainty change the main line of the simPH plot too? If so, this would mean that two different researchers get different plots using simPH vs. the formula or the predict function, given the same data (with significant effects or not; with outliers or not), which is quite misleading I think.

Comment: simPH doesn't create confidence intervals around the transformed point estimates like `predict`. It draws simulations from the multivariate normal distribution specified by the fitted model, then shows the central 50% and 95% of this simulated distribution. The central line is just the median of the sims. 

It is explicitly a different logic from `predict`. 

For very non-monotonic quantities of interest, like this one, `predict` point estimates give highly substantively misleading results compared to simPH. There is no way we have enough evidence for such a form based on 4 observations.

Comment: Added the comment on the differences to my main answer